# Javascript: How to check if something's been added to DOM?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, loading

Take a look at [this site](http://www.thisiswhyimbroke.com). When you scroll down, it automatically loads up a bit more of the page. Say that I have an event that runs on document.load. Is there a way to make it do that again when you scroll down and more stuff comes into view?

It's worth mentioning that I'm trying to design a way to sort of catch all instances like this, not just the specific site I mentioned which may very well have something to latch onto when it's doing the infinite scrolling.

Comment: Investigate the nature of the "scroll" event.

Comment: Usually, you (or your script) is the one adding elements to the DOM, so rather than add another event to catch when that happens, you could just call your functions when you add elements.

Comment: So you're looking for a sort of event to listen for whenever the DOM is added to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are deprecated [DOM3 Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Mutation_events), like `DOMSubtreeModified`, which fire whenever specific mutation event occur.  For performance and compatibility reasons, MDN strongly discourages their use, but they do exist.  I also believe that they don't provide information about what *kind* of mutation has occurred or any kind of before/after comparison.

There's a W3C draft for [DOM4 Mutation Observers](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html), which might be implemented in some browsers currently.  I know it's at least implemented in Chrome, which uses `WebKitMutationObserver` like so:

```
var observer = new WebKitMutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    // fired when a mutation occurs
    console.log(mutations, observer);
    // ...
});

// define what element should be observed
// and what types of mutations trigger the callback
observer.observe(document, {
  subtree: true,
  attributes: true
  //...
});
```

There's a full list of [mutation properties](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#mutationobserver) in the draft (scroll down to the green box).

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you're describing is often referred to as "[infinite scrolling](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/)".

**EDIT:** My answer above doesn't really answer your question.

The closest I can think of for a truly generic way of handling this, even when it's not your code that is adding elements to the DOM, is to use the [DOM Level 3 API Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Mutation_events), but they are **now deprecated and should not be used.**

There is ongoing work on a proposal for [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_Mutation_Observers) in DOM Level 4, but these are not yet standardised. However, [take a look at this article](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers) for an example implementation.

Comment: I can't speak for the downvoter with authority of course, but potential reasons include that you just posted a link without elaboration here (code examples etc), and that the link involves a jQuery plugin but the question isn't tagged jQuery.

Comment: Yeah true, actually I think the question is more about how to execute arbitrary code on DOM modification rather than how the scroll effect is achieved in itself, so I was wrong any way. :)